# How can we prove that $ \int f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} \, dx = \int f(y) \, dy $?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Often while solving an equation of the form
$$ f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} = g(x) $$
we integrate on both sides to obtain
$$
\int f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} \, dx = \int g(x) \, dx.
$$
We normally write it as
$$
\int f(y) \, dy = \int g(x) \, dx.
$$
But I don't understand how we replace $ \int f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} \, dx $ with $ \int f(y) \, dy $ on the LHS.

Is there a way to show that
$$
\int f(y) \frac{dy}{dx} \, dx = \int f(y) \, dy
$$

Comment: Hint: what are these integrals' $x$-derivatives?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: There are many similar questions already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737928/the-formalism-behind-integration-by-substitution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402303/understanding-the-differential-dx-when-doing-u-substitution, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just integration by substitution. Note for
$$
\int f(y)y' dx
$$
we can set ${u = y(x)}$ to obtain
$$
\rightarrow \int f(u)du
$$
but ${u=y}$, so
$$
\rightarrow \int f(y)dy
$$